Issue Deploying liquidity on Sepolia Testnet
I have deployed my contract to sepolia test net successfull but when I go to uniswap to try and provide some testnet liquidity whenever I try to select one of the tokens for the pair sepoliaEth uniswap is just unresponsive and it just brings me back to the Add liquidity screen and does nothing.
I start on this screen.

Then I go to select a token

And when I click on eth It just brings me right back to the Add liquidity picutre that I started on without any token selected just unresponsive.
I am connected to sepolia eth network. If I go to the swap section of uniswap it shows that I have test net eth so not sure what exacty is going on. Anyone have any suggestions ?

Seems like an ongoing issue with Uniswap on testnets.

@SYEDASADKAZMI  is this is common? I tried yesterday aswell But I encountered the same issue. Is it normal to not work for multiple days ?

Yeah, it’s persistent since the past few days. You can ask regarding the same in their Discord community.

Cool thanks mate

Just came here to find an answer...

No, pancakeswap dex doesn't support liquidity on testnet
https://pancakeswap.finance/liquidity/positions?chain=sepolia

Yes i know this question. uniswap dex not support testnet token if you deploy your ERC20 token in sepoile testnet so uniswap not support the testnet i don't why . you can do this another one dex like pancakeswape dex which is Support testnet token and mainnet token you can easily view your token in pancakswape and you can add liquidity successfully and remove liquidity successfully in pancakeswpae using testnet bnb.i already do this.
